# How can I solve the missing folder in foreach loop?

Tags: excel, foreach, ssis, tabular

I'm trying to add a path to the enumerator configuration but I have a problem.
There is nothing the "Browse for Folder" section.

What could be the problem here? It only shows Desktop and a subfolder which I have obscured for this posting.

[image: Browse for Folder]

couldn't find a similar problem on google.

Answer (score 1):

That is weird. It smells like a permission issue but I can't imagine an environment where you cannot navigate outside the desktop.

I do not experience the same thing when I click browse but to be honest, I've never clicked "Browse" before this question.

[image]

Use Windows Explorer and copy the path from there and paste into the `Folder` box of the Enumerator Configuration